# Can i loop this macro X amount of times but still increasing some cell references by +1?

Tags: excel, vba, loops, excel-2013

This macro may not be set out correctly/efficiently but it works so i didn't dare change it. I recorded it and didn't impute to much manually.

Basically I change the dates daily which is fine but I was thinking is there a way to loop the macro changing the cells highlighted in bold after each time the macro completes? i.e F107 becomes F108? Until there is no value in column F workbook cards? If this last part is too complicated i could just count the amount of times i need it to loop and enter that instead. Thanks :)

```
Sub Purge()
    Workbooks("Memos 04.09.2020").Sheets("Memos").Range("A1").AutoFilter Field:=4, Criteria1:=Workbooks("Cards 04.09.2020").Sheets("Cards").Range _ (**"F107"**).Value
    Workbooks("Transactions 04.09.2020").Sheets("Transactions").Range("A1").AutoFilter Field:=2, Criteria1:=Workbooks("Cards 04.09.2020").Sheets("Cards").Range _ (**"F107"**).Value
    Dim objWord As New Word.Application
    Workbooks("Cards 04.09.2020").Sheets("Cards").Range _ ("**B107**:**C107**").Copy
    
    With objWord  
        .Documents.Add  
        .Selection.PasteAndFormat (wdFormatPlainText)  
        .Selection.TypeParagraph
        .Visible = True

        Workbooks("Cards 04.09.2020").Sheets("Cards").Range _ ("**D107:F107**").Copy
        .Selection.PasteAndFormat (wdFormatPlainText)
        .Selection.TypeParagraph
        .Selection.TypeParagraph
        .Selection.TypeText ("Transactions")
        .Visible = True

        Workbooks("Transactions 04.09.2020").Sheets("Transactions").Range("E:G").Copy
        .Selection.PasteExcelTable False, True, False
        .Selection.TypeParagraph
        .Visible = True

        Workbooks("Memos 04.09.2020").Sheets("Memos").Range("E:K").Copy
        .Selection.TypeParagraph
        .Selection.TypeParagraph
        .Selection.TypeText ("Memos")
        .Selection.PasteExcelTable False, True, False
        .Visible = True
    End With
End Sub
```

Comment: Look into the following methods that range objects have. a) `.Offset()` references a nearby cell (like one down), b) `.Range()` expands the reference from a cell to a table with rows & columns and c) `.Cells()` which references cells within a range (like the 3rd row and 7th column).

Answer (score 0):

The Question is not completely clear.
If you want to Change the value from F107 to the last written Cell in F u can use this following code:

```
letztezeile = ActiveSheet.Cells(Rows.Count, 6).End(xlUp).Row
```

And you can try for example this in Brackets ("F"&letztezeile) to change the columns.

Comment: Basically the macro takes the account number from the cell i.e F107 and filters both the memos/transactions workbooks. Then it copies the information into a new word document. Then I have to manually change the F107 to the next row down F108 and run the macro again. Im trying to see if there is a way it will continue looping the macro until there is a blank cell say in F120 or something?

Comment: Each cell reference in the above code that has 107 would need to increase by one each time: B107 C107 D107 F107. There is 6 instances total, so once the word document had been made they would all change to 108 until there was a blank cell in F column under the cards workbook